# Normalizing by a non-linear max value

Tags: algorithms, average

I'm not entirely sure whether this question is fit for Mathematics or Stats, but here goes. I have tried to be as clear as possible, leading to quite a long post. Not everyone will read this post til the end, so I plan to add a bounty for those who do take the time to get through it all. If you need any more details, do let me know. If this question is not suited for Mathematics, please tell me in the comments and I'll delete it - though it seems that a problem concerning averaging and normalisation is ultimately well-fit for Math.

---

I am working on a language problem where you have two sentences (let's say a source sentence and a target sentence). These sentences are aligned, meaning that each word in each sentence is "connected" to zero, one *or more* words in the other sentence. (This is the task of [word alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitext_word_alignment), typically done for sentences in different languages that are translations of each other.) Let's assume for simplicity's sake that a word *must* be connected to at least one word in the other sentence (unlike the example given below).

[image: Example of world alignment]

The example above has the following alignment index pairs where the first item in a tuple (Python notation) is a source index and the second a target index. In my case, though, null alignment (here `(1, )`) is not possible, i.e. all words are aligned. Furthermore, my indices would start at 0.

```
[(1, ), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7)]
```

To measure the amount of syntactic shifts/reordering one has to do to translate the source sentence to the target sentence, I use a so-called *cross* value which actually counts the number of times that these alignments cross one another. Here is a visualization, where the circles are the crosses that we try to count.

[image: cross example]

Cross is calculated as follows ([paper](https://clinjournal.org/clinj/article/view/95); *not* written in a mathematical style - I'm a linguist and then a programmer, not by far a mathematician):

- sort the alignment pairs (`align_pairs`), first by source index, then by target
- only extract the second item of each tuple and store those (`tgt_idxs`)
- count all the occurrences where: for each combinations of target indices `t1, t2`, `t2` is smaller than `t1`

In Python ([online test](https://repl.it/@BramVanroy/AjarOffbeatArguments)):

```
from itertools import combinations

align_pairs = [(0,0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]

align_pairs.sort()
tgt_idxs = [pair[1] for pair in align_pairs]
cross = sum([1 for t1, t2 in combinations(tgt_idxs, 2) if t2 < t1])
print(cross)
# 1
```

The above is rather intuitive to understand, but a problem arises when trying to normalize this value into a value that lies between 0 and 1. To do so, we would need to get the maximally possible number of crosses for a given number of source indices and target indices. To do that, we can just create a list of all possible alignments pairs, i.e. a sequence where every source index is connected with every target index. The Python code is perhaps a bit too long to post here, but you can find it [online](https://repl.it/@BramVanroy/ShadowyWittyDevicedriver). It comes down to this:

```
# extract unique, sorted source and target indices
src_idxs = sorted(set(src_idxs))
tgt_idxs = sorted(set(tgt_idxs))

# make the product of both lists, leading
# to every source index being combined with every target
all_combs = list(product(src_idxs, tgt_idxs))

# ... calculate cross in the same way as above
```

This maximal value can then be used to normalize a cross value to a number between 0 and 1.

**The problem**, though, is that the maximal cross is not at all linear, i.e. for larger source and target sentences, the maximal cross will grow exponentially. As a consequence, one single cross between two short sentences will weigh a lot heavier than a single cross in two large sentences.

As an example, both of the following examples only have one cross but because the max_value for the second is so high, that one cross is almost nullified:

Given alignments `[(0, 1), (1, 0)]`:

- cross 1
- max_cross 1
- avg_cross 1.0

Given alignments `[(0,0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 4), (5, 5)]`

- cross 1
- max_cross 225
- avg_cross 0.0044444444444444444

From my perspective, it seems that a mathematically sound operation should be possible to counter the influence of the non-linear max_cross, but I can't get my head around it. Perhaps that intuition is even false, and there is no valid way to normalise this max value to a more reasonable value where the influence of the length is less important for the final value.

I am aware that other averaging options are possible, e.g. by number of alignments or average sentence length, but for other reasons I wish to get a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: The 'cross' is what we call an inversion for permutations. You want to count inversions, but in the end you want to store it as some number between $0$ and $1$, rather than the actual count, is that so? And why is that? In the sense that: what do you want to do with this number, that the case you present above is a problem?

Comment: That is correct. I wish to get a value between (inclusive) 0 and 1 where 0 means no crosses, and 1 all possible crosses. I would like to get a value between 0 and 1 to use it further down in my experiments and combine it (e.g. average it) with other values. To do so, I want them to have them in the same interval (0-1) to give all values the same weight.

Comment: What do you mean by same weight? By the way, you don't need to 'hand count' the maximum number of crosses: if the source has $n$ words and the target has $m$ words, then the number is $$\frac{m(m-1)n(n-1)}4.$$

Comment: For instance, if I wish to create a new metric that consists of the average cross (X) and some other value (Y) by averaging them ($(X+Y)/2$), then both X and Y should have the same scale. If for instance X ranges [0, inf+), and Y [0, 1] then the value of Y carries less weight than X in the overal average. I don't know whether "weight" is the correct term here.

Comment: Considering your formula: I knew there had to be a formula out there that could catch this without having to do the full operation again for all possible crosses, thanks! Can you explain the intuition behind it? (Incredible that you can do this so quickly. I am jealous of people with that mathematical touch. :-))

Comment: But you still want $X$ to be comparable between sentences of different lengths? I have little experience with language, but does a pair of sentences with the 'maximum' number of crosses actually occur in practice? It seems unreasonable to normalize by the maximum. Have you considered perhaps mapping the number of crosses to the normalized (in the statistical sense: $0$ mean and unit variance) distribution of crosses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103142/discussion-between-bram-vanroy-and-fimpellizieri).

Comment: The target indices stored (just before counting) in the case of maximum crossing, where the source has $n$ words and the target has $m$ words, is of the form

$$(1,2,3,\dots,m)(1,2,3,\dots,m)\dots(1,2,3,\dots,m)$$

where each term in parentheses shows up $n$ times. For each index with value $k$ there are $k-1$ indices with lower value. If the index with value $k$ is on the $i$-th parentheses, there will be $(n-i)$ parentheses after it. Hence we'll have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left((n-i)\sum_{k=1}^m(k-1)\right)$$

and simplifying this yields the formula.

Answer (score 1):

This will not map each cross count to a number in $[0,1]$, but might make numbers more comparable.

Suppose the source sentence has $n$ words and the target sentence has $m$ words.
For each word in the source and each word in the target, there may or may not be an edge connecting them.
This would mean there are $2^{mn}$ possible edge configurations.

For each such configuration, count the number of crosses and obtain a discrete distribution $X_{n,m}$ of the number of crosses, meaning

$$\Bbb P(X_{n,m} = k) = \frac{\text{# of configurations with cross count $k$}}{2^{mn}}.$$

We could then normalize this distribution and consider $Z = (X-\mu)/\sigma$, where $\mu = \Bbb E(X)$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $X$.
The number of crosses is $X$, the number you came up with is $\frac{X}{\max X}$.
I would try using $Z$ and see how it goes.

The caveat is that brute forcing the calculation of $X_{n,m}$ may not be computationally feasible, as the number of operations increases very fast with $m,n$.
There may be some smart combinatorics that can help here. I might try and tackle this later.